# Any regular mono is extremal

Tags: category-theory

I'm stuck proving that any regular mono is extremal.

Regular mono: any mono the arises as the equalizer of two morpshisms.

Extremal mono: $f$ extremal mono if $f=f'e$, $e$ epi implies $e$ iso.

I found a reference in "the joy of cats", proposition 7.6.2. The statement is the following:

Let $f: A \to B$ and $g:B \to C$ be morphisms:

1) If $f$ is an extremal mono and $g$ is a regular mono, then $gf$ is extremal.

2) If $gf$ is an extremal mono, then $f$ is an extremal mono.

3) If $gf$ is a regular mono and $g$ is a mono, then $f$ is a regular mono.

The proof of this statement is not such a problem, but I really don't understand how to prove the following

Corollary: any regular mono is extremal.

Comment: Is it not universality of equalizers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint :** Notice that every identity is an extremal monomorphism and apply 1).